# Question Regarding Span and Linear Combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I believe I understand both topics individually:  When asked if a linear system spans a certain R^n, the question is, "can any point be reached in that dimensional plane?"  Linear combination is multiplying a vector with a scalar and adding that to another vector being multiplied by a scalar and creating a linear system to solve to see if theres a unique solution or set of solutions.

My question is, how is it that finding a set of solutions or a unique solution, through the use of linear combination, will tell you if the system spans that dimensional plane?  I'm having a hard time understanding how know that theres a set of numbers that solved all 3 equations means that it spans the plane.  If anyone can explain this part in layman's terms, that would be great.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking here. As you mentioned we define a spanning set to be a set of vectors, $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$ such that, for any vector $u \in U$ we can write $u$ as a linear combination of $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$. Can you clarify what you want to know?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to word it.  When we solve a system of linear equations, we are finding a point in space that each linear equation touches.  So one point that they are all touch.  I'm unsure how this proves that the system spans the entire dimensional plane....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your question is about the geometry of the relation between invertibility of a matrix and the linear independence of its columns. Invertibility means that one can always solve $Ax=b$ for $x$, no matter the $b$. Indeed, $A^{-1}$ exists iff the columns (or rows) are linearly independent.
(Note that $Ax=b$ can be solvable (depending on $b$) even when $A$ does not have linearly independent columns; i.e. not spanning the space).

One can consider that $A$ is a map: it takes in a vector $x$ and produces a vector $Ax$.
The question of solving $Ax=b$ is the same as asking whether $b$ is in the column space (i.e. span of the matrix's column vectors). 
This is by definition of matrix multiplication, which produces $Ax$ by taking a linear combination of the columns of $A$. 
This is the connection between span and solving linear systems. We can only guarantee that the system is solvable if the span hits *all* the space of $\mathbb{R}^n$; if there are parts of the space that cannot be reached, then choosing a $b$ in those areas means we cannot solve the system.
In terms of linear independence, if two vectors out of $n$ are linearly dependent, then they give no new information about the space (and thus won't span it).

Another way to see this is by the Rank-Nullity Theorem (albeit in a less layman way), which says $\text{rank}(A)+\text{nullity}(A)=n$. 
Only if the dimension of the span of the columns is the *whole* space can we always solve the system.